# IIS URL Rewrite for redirect to FQDN

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to figure out the best URL rewrite rule to accomplish the following.

```
http://intranet/sites/default.aspx rewrite to http://intranet.domain.com/sites/default.aspx

http://intranet rewrite to http://intranet.domain.com
```

Also in IIS the URL binding is set to "intranet" for that web application

Hope that makes sense. Can someone please help with the rewrite rule?

Comment: Have you tried someting so far?

Comment: Yes, nothing seem to work and I must admit I haven't done a lot of rewrites before. The only URL Rewrites I did in the past are  request uri redirects.

Comment: So the rule should rewrite any requested path or only `sites/default.aspx`?

Comment: no, http://intranet/* to http://intranet.domain.com/* meaning any deep URL should redirect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the rule I would use:

```
<rule name="Intranet redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^intranet$" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://intranet.domain.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

It will match any requested path (`url="(.*)"`) on the host exactly named `http://intranet` (`pattern="^intranet$"` and with `https` been turned off) and redirect it to `http://intranet.domain.com/{R:0}` (where `{R:0}` is a back reference containing whatever path was requested).

Comment: This works!! I missed the $ at the end of pattern, probably causing redirect loop I think. Thanks for your time.