# Redirect to FQDN in IIS Not Working

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

None of the answers I've found to questions like this (notably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006963/iis-url-rewrite-for-redirect-to-fqdn)) work for me, so here I go.

We are running IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012 R2. We have a wildcard certificate (*.mydomain.com) installed on the server. On the Default Web Site we have a single binding to accept incoming https requests on port 443. I have a second Web Site set with a single binding to accept incoming http requests on port 80.

On the latter Web Site I've created a URL Rewrite rule to redirect all incoming non-HTTP traffic to `https://myserver.mydomain.com{REQUEST_URI}`, and this works perfectly. If I browse to either `http://myserver.mydomain.com/homepage` or `http://myserver/homepage`, I am sucessfully redirected to the HTTPS version of the site with the full domain name included and thus it loads just fine.

If I browse to `https://myserver.mydomain.com/homepage`, the site also loads perfectly.

However, I am trying to create another URL Rewrite rule on the Default Web Site so that requests to `https://myserver/homepage` (Note: HTTPS but the full domain name is omitted) are redirected to the `https://myserver.mydomain.com/homepage`. The reason for this is that the SSL certificate is only matched if the full domain is included. As it stands, if I enter `https://myserver/homepage` I get a security warning (`NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`).

I've created the rule which I think should work, based on the answer I linked to above, but it doesn't work and I don't know why. My rule look like this:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to FQDN" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^myserver$" />
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="https://myserver.mydomain.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Even with this rule in place and enabled, when I browse to `https://myserver/homepage` I get the security message. What am I doing wrong with this rule?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you have SSL only for `*.mydomain.com`. And when you accessing `https://myserver` it will return certificate error because your cert is not valid for this domain.

For better understanding about steps during SSL connection:
[image]

In your case, the problem is between step 2 and 3

Comment: I understand the mismatch between the requested URL and the SSL certificate, but I'm trying to handle that by having requests which don't contain the domain forwarded to the equivalent URL with the domain included so that they match the certificate. Are you saying that this isn't possible if the request comes in via HTTPS?