# Best way to redirect all HTTP to HTTPS in IIS and redirect to FQDN

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I've read https://serverfault.com/questions/893315/best-way-to-redirect-all-http-to-https-in-iis and [IIS URL Rewrite for redirect to FQDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006963/iis-url-rewrite-for-redirect-to-fqdn) and was wondering what the best way was to combine the two to effectively redirect something like `http://skateboarders` to `https://skateboarders.domain.com`

Would it result in something like the below?

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <globalRules>
      <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
          <add input="{HTTPS}" ignoreCase="true" matchType="Pattern" negate="false" pattern="OFF" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://skateboarders.domain.com/{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </globalRules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

or

```
<rule name="Intranet redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^intranet$" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://skateboarders.domain.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: As it is possible to write tons of equivalent (or at least quite similar) rules, you won't find "the best way". To tell if a rule is correct or not, enable FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

What about try this rule?

```
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://skateboarders.domain.com/{R:1}" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="skateboarders" />
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
```